# Множественное удаление элементов из массива

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, функции, dom

У меня не получается сделать так, чтобы удалялись все выбранные элементы. По какой-то причине удаляется только часть. Возможно это связано с тем, что после удаления первого элемента бывший второй становится первым

```js
const data = ["Nastya", "Katya", "Lena", "Lera"];
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete");

function showData() {
 data.forEach(item => {
 let p = document.createElement("p");
 p.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'>" + item;
    content.appendChild(p);
 });
}

showData();

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
 let checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
 let checkedInd = [];
 Array.from(checkbox, (item, i) => {
   if (item.checked) checkedInd.push(i);
 });
 if (checkedInd !== []) {
   checkedInd.forEach(item => {
     data.splice(item, 1);
   });
   content.innerHTML = "";
   showData();
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Comment: достаточно единожды запомнить, что если вы в цикле удаляете что-либо из массива, то перебирать его надо с конца.

Comment: `if (checkedInd !== [])` не имеет смысла, кстати - всегда будет давать true) Потому что `console.log( [] == [] ) // false` — сравниваются два совершенно разных массива, даже если их содержимое одинаковое, они всё равно не равны. Если хочется, чтобы для пустого массива не выполнялся код, можно `if ( checkedInd.length )` — даст false только если длина равна нулю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможно это связано с тем, что после удаления первого элемента бывший второй становится первым

С этим и связано. Если нужно в одном цикле удалить по несколько элементов из массива, перебирать нужно с конца, т.к. индексы обновляются после удаления каждого элемента:

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

arr.forEach( (item, i) => arr.splice(i, 1) ); // Хотелось удалить все 6 элементов

console.log( arr );

/*
Первый удалили, → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Второй удалили, → [1, 3, 4, 5]
Третий удалили, → [1, 3, 5]
Четвертого уже нет!)
*/
```

В вашем случае, если очень хочется через forEach (он не умеет ходить справа налево), можно перед перебором добавить `reverse()` на массив.

```js
const data = ["Nastya", "Katya", "Lena", "Lera"];
let content = document.getElementById("content");
let deleteBtn = document.getElementById("delete");

function showData() {
 data.forEach(item => {
 let p = document.createElement("p");
 p.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'>" + item;
    content.appendChild(p);
 });
}

showData();

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
 let checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
 let checkedInd = [];
 Array.from(checkbox, (item, i) => {
   if (item.checked) checkedInd.push(i);
 });
 checkedInd.reverse().forEach(item => {
   data.splice(item, 1);
 });
 content.innerHTML = "";
 showData();
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```

Но оно один раз проходит и переворачивает, а потом еще раз перебирает. В таких случаях легче использовать обычный цикл в обратную сторону:

```
for( let i = checkedInd.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
  data.splice( checkedInd[i], 1);
}
```

Но... Можно было не обновлять весь список после каждого удаления, а просто взять и удалить только то, что нужно:

```js
const data = ["Nastya", "Katya", "Lena", "Lera"];

showData();
handleDelete();

function showData(){
  let content = document.getElementById("content");
  let html = data.map( name => {
    return '<p><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"> ' + name + '</p>';
  }).join(''); // Нет реальной разницы, вставлять строку или createElement. Как удобнее.
  
  content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

function handleDelete(){
  let deleteBtn  = document.getElementById("delete");
  
  deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let names = document.querySelectorAll('#content .checkbox');
    
    for( let i = names.length - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){
      if( names[i].checked ){
        data.splice( i, 0 );
        names[i].parentNode.outerHTML = "";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="delete">Delete</button>
```